# I am not able to run php file in my ubuntu os

Tags: xubuntu, lamp, php7

I have installed apache, mysql and PHP. But still I'm not able to run my php file.

Please help me. [http://localhost/PHP/newfile.php](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6kFLG.png)

Comment: This is not a php problem, but an apache configuration problem. file not found is quite clear.

Comment: Do you see Apache page when you chech localhost in your browser? If yes, that means there is no problem in your installation. Just you need to introduce Apache where to look for your files to handle

Answer (score 2):

If browsing to localhost works for you and viewing a specific php does not. This tells me that the php file is not in the correct directory. By default apache2 looks in /var/www/html.

If you will be developing php websites, might I recommend that you take a look at setting up virtual hosts. This is a straight forward process if you follow the many excellent tutorials on the web. I use virtual hosts for all my local development on Ubuntu.